# Using django-haystack, how do I order results by content type

Tags: django, django-haystack

I'm using django-haystack for a search page on my site, and I want to order all the results by their content type. Is there a way I can do that?
To make it simpler, suppose I have a single application and several classes.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from [`How to order search results by Model`](http://groups.google.com/group/django-haystack/browse_thread/thread/316154f2604a20c9/f6228681a9008977?#f6228681a9008977):

> You can do
>   `SearchQuerySet().order_by('django_ct')`.
>   As a warning, this throws out
>   relevancy. The only way to keep
>   relevancy & group by model is either
>   to run many queries (one per model -
>   usually performant thanks to query
>   caching) or to run the query and
>   post-process the results, regrouping
>   them as you go.

from [`searchindex api`](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-haystack/en/latest/searchindex_api.html):

> Haystack reserves the following field
>   names for internal use: id, django_ct,
>   django_id & content. The name & type
>   names used to be reserved but no
>   longer are.
>
> You can override these field names
>   using the HAYSTACK_ID_FIELD,
>   HAYSTACK_DJANGO_CT_FIELD &
>   HAYSTACK_DJANGO_ID_FIELD if needed.

Comment: And what should I do if all I want is to establish each model's relevancy? Run queries for each one of them?

Answer (score 6):

Not sure what you mean by content type, but if you are talking about group by models, I have this working

```
        {% with page.object_list as results %}
            {% regroup results|dictsort:"verbose_name_plural" by verbose_name_plural as grouped_objects %}
            {% for ct in grouped_objects %}
                {{ ct.grouper }}
                {% for result in ct.list %}
                    <p>
                        <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.object }}</a>
                    </p>
                {% endfor %}
            {% empty %}
                <p>No results found.</p>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endwith %}
```