# Finding the number of haystack results by model type?

Tags: django, django-haystack, whoosh

Let's say I have 3 models (Note, Comment, Article) that I want to search using django-haystack and I setup 3 indexes like this.

```
class NoteIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    author = CharField(model_attr='user', faceted=True)
    pub_date = DateTimeField(model_attr='pub_date')

class CommentIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    author = CharField(model_attr='user', faceted=True)
    pub_date = DateTimeField(model_attr='pub_date')

class ArticleIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    author = CharField(model_attr='user', faceted=True)
    pub_date = DateTimeField(model_attr='pub_date')
```

When I get my results, I'm able to use the author facet to show the number of results by author.

```
>>> from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
>>> sqs = SearchQuerySet().facet('author')
>>> sqs.facet_counts()
{
    'dates': {},
    'fields': {
        'author': [
            ('john', 4),
            ('daniel', 2),
            ('sally', 1),
            ('terry', 1),
        ],
    },
    'queries': {}
}
```

But how can I find out how many results by Model type? For example.

Notes: 4
Comment: 2
Article: 1

Ideally I would like to filter on it, like a normal facet. I'm using the FacetedModelSearchForm now, and I can see the model types, just can't get the count values. Is this possible? If so, how?

**Similar Questions:**

It looks like someone else asked this question as well, but maybe didn't ask the question clear enough.

[Django Haystack faceting on the model type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809811/django-haystack-faceting-on-the-model-type)

This one is similar but they just want to order by the content type, I want the count by content type.

[Using django-haystack, how do I order results by content type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414632/using-django-haystack-how-do-i-order-results-by-content-type)

Here is another similar question, but not quite the same, and once again no answer as well.

[Django Haystack Faceting examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862539/django-haystack-faceting-examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried just creating another facet for that? The only potentially difficult part would be getting the model name. Most likley, you would want to use `verbose_name` so it's more readable, which you can get from `_meta.verbose_name`. However, something like the following code probably *wouldn't* work:

```
model = CharField(model_attr='_meta.verbose_name', faceted=True)
```

So, you could simply add a method to your model to just return this value:

```
def get_model_name(self):
    return self._meta.verbose_name
```

Then:

```
model = CharField(model_attr='get_model_name', faceted=True)
```

All of this is untested though, as I've never needed to do this myself.

Comment: That was what I was looking for, I'll try it out and see if that works for me. If I have to change anything, I'll let you know so you can update your answer.

Comment: ``model_attr="_meta__verbose_name_plural"`` works. It's ugly, but not as ugly as adding a stupid method to X different models. I blame Haystack.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to regroup objects in django template through regroup django'stemplatetag associated with dictsort django's template filter (regroup works only with ordered queryset):

```
{% with page.object_list as results %}

   {% regroup results|dictsort:"model_name" by model_name as grouped_objects %}

   {% for ct in grouped_objects %}

      {{ ct.grouper }} (Total: {{ct.list|length}}

      {% for result in ct.list %}

      <p><a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.object }}</a></p>

      {% endfor %}

   {% empty %}

      <p>No results found.</p>

   {% endfor %}

{% endwith %}
```

If you don't want to lose your original order be sure to pas the SearchQueryset ordered by ('model_name',*your_order_fields)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
sqs1 = SearchQuerySet().models(Note).facet('author')
print sqs1.facet_counts()

sqs2 = SearchQuerySet().models(Comment).facet('author')
print sqs2.facet_counts()

sqs3 = SearchQuerySet().models(Article).facet('author')
print sqs3.facet_counts()

# multiple models are allowed as well:
sqs4 = SearchQuerySet().models(Note, Article).facet('author')
print sqs4.facet_counts()
```

This limits the `SearchQuerySet` to one or more models before computing the facet counts.

Comment: That might work, but will it give me the # of results for each model type as well as author?

Comment: I'm not sure as I have not used this before. Just try and see.